# Persistent non-interactive FTP session for usage in shell scripts

Tags: linux, authentication, ftp, expect, non-interactive

I would like to script a complex scenario of file transfers from Linux to a Windows FTP server (detecting new/changed files and then transfer) and I am unable to find a command-line ftp client which supports sending files over a persistent (one time login) session on non-interactive mode.

`ssh/scp` with password-less authentication is not an option, since I have no access to the Windows FTP server.

For example using `lftp`

```
`lftp -u user,pass -p 21 -e "mput newfile.txt;"` 10.0.0.100
```

will upload my file to the server, but requires authentication/handshaking to happen on every request, which takes a long time and severely slows down the transfers.

I am wondering whether there is a way to authenticate once, establish a persistent connection and then sending the files over this connection. `lftp` and other clients are able to do this in interactive mode (connect and then perform multiple commands until quitting).

Therefore:

- Is there an FTP client on Linux which may operate like this in non-interactive mode?
- Alternatively, is there a way to simulate this behaviour, scripting over the interactive mode? Maybe something utilizing `expect` with `netcat/telnet` and/or named pipes?

Comment: Aside from automating the password entry, lftp can be scripted already: https://web.archive.org/web/20111024014512/http://tutorials.papamike.ca/pub/lftp.html#scripts

Comment: Many languages implement FTP clients, so you can create as arbitarily complex scripts as you like: [Tcl](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/ftp/ftp.html), [Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP), [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html?highlight=ftp#module-ftplib)

Comment: @glennjackman I know that `lftp` can read a set from commands from a file and that I can also pipe multiple commands into it, but that does not solve what I want to achieve. As I stated, I want to upload files when they are made available (detecting new/changed files). Thus I cannot prepopulate a script with commands, I have to initiate a new transfer when the files are detected. This is the reason I want the session to be kept open to avoid reconnecting all the time.

Comment: Thank you @glennjackman. I know that, but I am interested in a command-line/shell script solution. I'm sure someone with more experience in using `expect` and `telnet/netcat` can come up with something interesting which may be applied to other use cases as well

Comment: how often do new files come along?

Comment: @glennjackman about 24 files per minute and I have to send them over a (sometimes unreliable) 3G connection, that's why the ping time is significant and the handshaking is slowing transfers considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you can do something like this Tcl:

```tcl
package require ftp
set conn [ftp::Open server user pass]
while true {
    after 5000          ;# sleep 5 seconds
    foreach newfile [glob -nocomplain *] {
        puts "sending $newfile"
        ftp::Put $newfile
        file delete $newfile
    }
}
```

The expect would be similar. untested:

```tcl
set timeout -1
spawn lftp -u user,pass server
expect "> "
while true {
    sleep 5
    foreach newfile [glob -nocomplain *] {
        puts "sending $newfile"
        send "put $newfile\r"
        expect "> "
        file delete $newfile
    }
    send "\r"          ;# "hit enter" as a keep-alive
}
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn. How could I make sure that the connection is kept alive? And if it is not, restart it in the loop then continue sending new files

Comment: you'd have to check the output or result of the "put", if there's an error, you'd loop back to re-spawn

Comment: Is there a command in `expect` that performs error handling and branching to the spawn command? In a shell script that would be for example `attempt_transfer || respawn`

Comment: No, expect does not know what the command's exit status is  on the spawned process. After `expect "> "`, you have to examine the contents of `$exect_out(0,string)` for error messages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make some tests and let you know.